# Error: ng:areq Bad Argument and argument not defined in ANGULARJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

I 'm new in AngularJS 
I wrote a app that have an error doesn't show entire code. that part of code that have angular code didn't appear.

**MAIN.js file**

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
'ngRoute',
'artistController'
]);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
when('/list' , {
templateUrl: 'list/list.html',
controller: 'artistController'
 }).otherwise({
 redirectTo: '/list'
});
}]);

var artistController = angular.module('artistController' , []);

artistController.controller("ListController", [
  "$scope", "$http" ,function ($scope , $http) {
  $http.get('file:///C:/wamp/www/angular - copy/data.json').success(function (data) {
    $scope.artists = data;
  });
}
]);
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>angular</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///C:/wamp/www/angular/bootstrap-3.3.7-    dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" title="no title">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///C:/wamp/www/angular - copy/main.css" media="screen" title="no title">
<script src="file:///C:/wamp/www/angular/angular-1.5.8/angular.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="file:///C:/wamp/www/angular/angular-1.5.8/angular-route.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="file:///C:/wamp/www/angular - copy/main.js" charset="utf-8">        </script> 
</head>
<body>
<div class="containor" ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**list.html**

```
  <div>
 <h2>Search directory</h2>
 <label>Search:</label>
 <input placeholder="Search for your person" autofocus="" ng-model="query">   </input>
  <label>By:
   <select ng-model="artistOrder">
    <option value="lastName">lastName</option>
    <option value="firstName">firstName</option>
  </select>
  </label>
 </div>
 <ul class="background" ng-controller="ListController">
 <li class="center" ng-repeat="x in artists | filter:query |  orderBy:artistOrder">
   <img src="img.png" alt="photo" />
    <h1 class="col-lg-4">{{ x.firstName | uppercase }}</h1>
    <h2 class="col-lg-5">{{ x.lastName }}</h2>
 </li>
</ul>
</section>
```

in chrome I got a error `Argument 'artistController' is not aNaNunction, got undefined`

Any idea?
Thanks Regard

Comment: It looks like you should be hanging your artistController off of your app module. You've kind of just declared it out in the open on it's own, so it's not being found in your ng-app module (that being, "app").

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you are not doing other errors, you need to change your controller to:

```
angular.module('app') //if you do var app = ..., you can also do app.controller
       .controller('ListController', ListController);

ListController.$inject = [ "$scope", "$http" ];

function ListController( $scope, $http ){
   $http.get('file:///C:/wamp/www/angular - copy/data.json').success(function (data) {
     $scope.artists = data;
   });
}
```

Take a look at [AngularJS Documentation on Controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller).

Comment: I add your code to app but still not working . could you help me a little more? thanks

Comment: You also need to remove artistController from app dependencies